# What is the meaning of "screening-out a perturbation" in a nanosurfaces context?

Tags: solid-state-physics, material-science, semiconductor-physics, semiclassical, nanoscience

When reading my lecturer's notes on the *Thomas-Fermi screening length*, I am told that:

"*The Thomas-Fermi screening length $\lambda_{TF}$ is a
rough guide to how rapidly an electron gas can
screen out a perturbation.*"

**I don't really understand what is meant by this.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that you have a point charge $q$ and you want to "hide" (screen) it from the world so that no one can detect its charge. You could accomplish this by building a spherical shell around it with charge $-q$. An electron gas does something similar. Your charge $q$ attracts electrons from the gas that help hide the charge in a similar way. In the Thomas-Fermi model, you'll end up with a potential $V \propto \frac{e^{-\lambda r}}{r}$ instead of $V \propto \frac{1}{r}$ for a normal Coulomb potential.